# what does out in **out string [][] teams** mean

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-6.0

what does **out** mean in a multidimensional param, if it's possible write an eg please, I'll really appreciate

```cs
public string GetTeamsInfo(out string[][] teams)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: It has nothing to do with the string being multidimensional. It's a basic feature of C#.

Comment: Note : string[][] is not a multidimensional array it is a jagged array (an array of arrays) a multidimensional array would be declared as [,]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

out means the parameter is an {out}put parameter

opposed to the default input parameter (note: an input parameter is not the same as a parameter using the `in` modifier, that is an **input only** parameter and imposes it own requirements)

this means it has no value at the beginning of the function and you need to assign one for it to be passed back to the calling code

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

```
public string GetTeamsInfo(out string[][] teams)
{
    teams = new string[3][4];
    return "test";
}

string[][] teams;
//here teams is null
string text = GetTeamsInfo(out teams);
//here teams is a array of string[]
```

Comment: `in` is *not* the default, the default is to pass by value

Comment: input is the default direction, the `in` keyword means 'readonly by reference',

Comment: I realized that's what you meant, but it's not immediately obvious. Maybe clarify